# Vue JS: How to style the active <a> tag in a router-link?

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to edit my router-link so that the color of the **text** as well as the background changes when the link is active.

With the `.router-link-exact-active` class, I've set it so the background correctly changes from some default, but the text colour always stays the same?

Indeed, the only way to change the colour of the link's text at all (including to the non-active, default colour of blue) is by styling the  tag, itself.

My code for the link is below:

```
<router-link :to="{path: '/Homer'}" exact tag="li"><a>Homer</a></router-link>
```

The CSS for the  tag (which sets the colour before the link is active - it's standard colour):

```
a {
  color:royalblue;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

And the CSS for the router-exact-link-active is:

```
.router-link-exact-active {
  background: yellow;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: red;
  font-variant: italic;
}
```

So, the li's background colour (since the router-link is set to an li tag, of course) changes correctly, but the text colour remains blue no matter what.

Isn't the colour of the text (and other set styles) **supposed to cascade** down from the parent li's assigned active class to the  tag (both when the router-link is and isn't active) - such as in this tutorial https://youtu.be/yn0_6T4HwHs?t=266?

If not, how do I style the text when it's active - I'm guessing I would attach some kind of active class to the  - one that isn't a:active, since the text isn't 'active' once the mouse is done clicking on it - but I can't seem to find the right way to do that?

Apologies if this is a very basic question, but I've looked around for the answer and can't find it.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Finding the culprit

When you see an unexpected style applied, given no user/author style, the likely culprit is the user agent style sheet. You can confirm this  in the [DevTools computed styles pane](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/elements-styles#computed_style) for the inspected `a` element. Find the `color` property (the first item), expand the item to reveal the applicable styles, listed from highest priority to lowest. The highest priority style is the one that is currently applied.

[image]

## To inherit color

If you want the `a` element to inherit its color from its parent (`.router-link-exact-active` in this case), apply [`inherit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit).

```
a {
  color: inherit;
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/6wnv6j40jw?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue)

Comment: Thanks very much! This helped me solve it. The inspector element helped me see the precedence lvls clearly, and indeed there was some over ranking style - though from something called the 'PreferenceStyleSheet', apparently. I couldn't figure out where that comes from, or how to modify/remove it, but creating an a{ color: inherit} style as you said indeed solved it. To be clear on how for the others learning from this, the a{...} being the most specific style for <a> text had the highest precedence of the styles, and setting a{ color: inherit} simply means a's color is the same as li's. Thanks!

Comment: works flawlessly!

Answer (score 5):

They do cascade, but you have a default style for **a** tags that is more specific and as such your **li** style doesn’t apply.

You need to set a style that is more specific than the default one.

```
.router-link-exact-active a {}
```

should do the trick

Comment: Thanks, that seems to correctly style the text when it's active. But, still I'm having the problem that having some sort of a{...} style is the only way to style the text? Meaning that when I remove all references in the CSS to styling colour, except the li{...} (or if I repeat it with some higher parent) the text colour does not change. Only using an a{...} or ...-active a{...} as in above can I get the text to change. Again I'm confused, because I thought that without the more specific style (as you mentioned) in place, the styles would cascade down? Where could I be going wrong? Thanks!